# When using cx_Oracle does Oracle need to be installed on all computers with the python application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I created an exe of my program that communicates with an oracle database using cx_Oracle to create excel sheets. If someone else uses this exe will they need Oracle installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any computer that runs Python programs using cx_Oracle will need an 'Oracle client' installed.  This is the set of Oracle libraries needed by cx_Oracle that allow connections to a database.  The database can be on a remote computer.  The Oracle client libraries are available in three different installs:

- With the Oracle Database install
- With a 'full' Oracle Client install
- From Oracle Instant Client

The most common in your case would be to use Oracle Instant Client, which is relatively small and is simple to install.

You download the Instant Client 'Basic' package matching your operating system and the Python architecture (32 or 64 bit).  Unzip it.  Set your operating system search path such as PATH (on Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ldconfig (on Linux) to the directory you unzipped.

Instant Client Downloads and instructions are at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html

cx_Oracle installation instructions are at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html